# I can't use change event on a range input with cordova in ios

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, sugarcube

I'm making a game with Sugarcube and I making a slider for a volume music and effects.
but i can't make that the change and input events are listened in a cordova aplication in my ifone.

i tested it in my pc with Microsoft Edge, in my mac with Safari, and in my android like apk compiled with Cordova.

i compiled it for ios with change and input event for my inputs range don't work.

here is the code:

```
<label for="musica">Activar música</label><input type="checkbox" id="musica">
<label for="vmusica" id="smusica">Volumen de la música</label><input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="10" id="vmusica">
<label for="efectos">Activar efectos de sonido</label><input type="checkbox" id="efectos">
<label for="vefectos" id="sefectos">Volumen de los  efectos de sonido</label><input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="10" id="vefectos">
<script>
document.querySelector("#vmusica").value=parseInt(SugarCube.State.variables.vmusica*100);
document.querySelector("#musica").checked=SugarCube.State.variables.sonidito;
document.querySelector("#vmusica").style.display =document.querySelector("#musica").checked ? "inline-block" : "none";
document.querySelector("#smusica").style.display =document.querySelector("#musica").checked ? "inline-block" : "none";
document.querySelector("#vefectos").value=parseInt(SugarCube.State.variables.vefectos*100);
document.querySelector("#efectos").checked=SugarCube.State.variables.efectitos;
document.querySelector("#vefectos").style.display =document.querySelector("#efectos").checked ? "inline-block" : "none";
document.querySelector("#sefectos").style.display =document.querySelector("#efectos").checked ? "inline-block" : "none";
document.querySelector("#efectos").addEventListener("change", function(){
SugarCube.State.variables.efectitos=this.checked ? true : false;
SugarCube.State.display("efectos",SugarCube.Story.get("efectos"));
});
document.querySelector("#musica").addEventListener("change", function(){
SugarCube.State.variables.sonidito=this.checked ? true : false;
if (this.checked) {
SugarCube.State.display("sonido",SugarCube.Story.get("efectos"));
}
else{
SugarCube.SimpleAudio.select(":playing").pause();
}
SugarCube.State.display("efectos",SugarCube.Story.get("efectos"));
});
document.querySelector("#vmusica").addEventListener("change", () => {
SugarCube.State.variables.vmusica=parseFloat(document.querySelector("#vmusica").value/100);
SugarCube.SimpleAudio.select(":playing").volume(SugarCube.State.variables.vmusica);
});
document.querySelector("#vefectos").addEventListener("change", () => {
SugarCube.State.variables.vefectos=parseFloat(document.querySelector("#vefectos").value/100);
});
</script>
```

i want that when i change the slider for example 10% the music or effects the sounds low o up the volume in real time.
in my pc and in my android works perfectly but in ios no.
thanks, Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I'm reviewing new user questions: some feedback: 1. can you restate the problem within the Question text? 2. can you state what you are expected? 3. consider improving the syntax and spelling; change `i'm` and `i` to `I'm` and `I`, the word `efects` is spelled `effects`, the browser Safari is specific and could be capitalized `Safari`.

Comment: thanks sorry for my bad english and my terrible post.

Comment: hey, when i investigate most deeply in the ios documentation of webkit, i discover that the audio tag volumme property in webkit only can be made in 1 or in 0. so my solution was use cordova media to manipulate the audio volumme in convenience.